# Как изменить цвет кнопок в toolbar?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Решил изменить цветовую гамму на белый и синий цвет.

И тут у меня появилась проблема из-за того что я сделал tooldbar белого цвета у меня теперь не видно навигационных иконок и текста

[image: Приложение]

Сам стиль toolbar

```
<style name="mainToolbar">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28620883/7540461

Comment: Посмотри этот ответ по этой ссылке https://stackoverflow.com/a/28631979/7939955